# Serializing class to .json file

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

just trying to do a simple serialize(first time trying).
actually had this working up until I changed a few things and added a deserialize and added a class that made my other way no longer work.

basically I took what I had for deserialize json to object and tried to just reverse the order of things. but now I get an error at a foreach loop I'm not sure if I even need.
Once I get the serialize working I'm sure I will also be stuck on how to format the string as it enters the .json file so it appends properly but that is for another day.

here is error i received

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

i receive this exception on the line `foreach(var translogs in Logs.transLogs)`

here is my event.

**Code**

```cs
private void toolPull_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double cost = Convert.ToDouble(active_Cost.Text);
    int serial = Convert.ToInt32(transactionSerial_Box.Text);
    DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
    TransactionLogs Logs = new TransactionLogs();
    foreach(var translogs in Logs.transLogs)
    {
        translogs.Employee = transactionEmployee_Box.Text;
        translogs.Serial = serial;
        translogs.Cost = cost;
        translogs.Description = active_Description.Text;
        translogs.CurrentDate = timeNow;
    }

    string stringJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Logs);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\transactionlog.json", append: true);
    sw.WriteLine(stringJson);
    sw.Close();
}
```

**Here is the class to work with json**

```cs
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class TransactionLogs
    {
        [JsonProperty("TransactionLog")]
        public List<TransactionLog> transLogs { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TransactionLog
    {
        [JsonProperty("employee")]
        public string Employee { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currentDate")]
        public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("serial")]
        public int Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isPull")]
        public bool IsPull { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cost")]
        public double Cost { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**and here is json file**

```json
{
   "TransactionLog":[
      {
         "employee":"Joey",
         "currentDate":"2021-11-03T11:49:13.5741628-04:00",
         "serial":1111,
         "description":"1/2-20 Threadmill",
         "isPull":true,
         "_ost":25.68
      },
      {
         "employee":"joey",
         "currentDate":"2021-11-03T11:50:34.6344474-04:00",
         "serial":1000,
         "description":"1/2-20 Threadmill",
         "isPull":true,
         "cost":25.68
      },
      {
         "employee":"john",
         "currentDate":"2021-11-03T11:50:40.9956616-04:00",
         "serial":2000,
         "description":"1/2-20 Threadmill",
         "isPull":true,
         "cost":25.68
      },
      {
         "employee":"Jim",
         "currentDate":"2021-11-03T11:51:24.5559292-04:00",
         "serial":4565,
         "description":"1/2-20 Threadmill",
         "isPull":true,
         "cost":25.68
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: **What error?** We need more specific information about what's wrong. Please clearly explain what's not working about your attempt. We're more than happy to then help :)

Comment: The list translogs is probably null from not being initialized. Try creating a new instance first.

Comment: add transLogs initialization to TransactionLogs class constructor

Comment: can you explain how to do that?

Comment: `public TransactionLogs() { transLogs = new(); }` should do the trick in C# 9. Add it to first partial class.

Comment: @JoeFisher Or as an alternative: `public List<TransactionLog> transLogs { get; set; } = new List<TransactionLog>();`

Comment: so @quian your answer won't work for me as I have this project under C#7 apparently, and @peter Csala yours threw an error in my partial class, but it did not in the top level class. however all that happened was i got an empty string. this is what was added to my log. `{"TransactionLog":[]}`

Comment: @JoeFisher What error does it throw?

Comment: looks to be exactly the same as before, `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` when i add that code to my partial class. if i add to my main class there is no exception caused, but it gives empty string

Comment: It is indeed an empty string, since your `transLogs` property is initialized but does not contain any entry in it. You have to call `Add` on the the list to populate the collection.

Comment: would i be using this instead of my foreach loop? im not familiar with add just yet. looking into it now

Comment: @JoeFisher Instead of the foreach loop try this: `var transLogs = new TransactionLog(); transLogs.Employee = ...` set all the properties then `Logs.transLogs = new List<TransactionLog>(); Logs.transLogs.Add(transLogs);`

Comment: that did it. I'm slowly getting to understand this stuff but its a rough road thats for sure. thank you for your help. if you add that as an answer i would be happy to mark it as the answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

Let me capture here the outcome of the comments.

There were two problems with these two lines:

```
TransactionLogs Logs = new TransactionLogs();
foreach(var translogs in Logs.transLogs)
```

- The `TransactionLogs`'s `transLogs` collection is not initialized, that's caused the NRE
- After fixing that the `foreach` went through on an empty collection

The fix for the first problem:

```
Logs.transLogs = new List<TransactionLog>();
```

The fix for the second problem:

```
var transLogs = new TransactionLog()
{
    Employee = transactionEmployee_Box.Text;
    Serial = serial;
    Cost = cost;
    Description = active_Description.Text;
    CurrentDate = timeNow;
};
Logs.transLogs.Add(transLogs);
```

So, rather than iterating through the empty collection, you had to populate it by adding a new member.